# Is it possible to host an ASPX web site on Linux?

Tags: asp.net, linux

We are trying to convert a lot of things at work over to Linux Red hat.  Recently Windows Server 2003 was installed.  We are currently hosting an asp .net web site on the windows server machine, what I'm wondering is if there is any software that will allow you to host the same web site on linux?

Comment: Just to follow up a bit, the page i'm trying to get running does have VBscripting in it so mono project wont support that.

Comment: Isn't VBScript browser based, not server based?

Comment: Go here http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical and search VBScript.

What about VBScript and VBA? 

Those languages are simpler to implement due to the restricted dependency on external COM objects, but there are no plans at this point to implement them by the Mono team.

Comment: Are you sure it is VBScript and not VB.NET?

Comment: VBScript and VBA are not supported by ASP.Net, so your question is nonsensical. Are you using VBScript with ASP or VB.NET with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 13):

To a certain extent, yes. [The Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) has support for ASP.NET 2.0 web sites.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider running a windows virutal machine on a linux host using virtualization software like vmware.  I don't know if this fits with what you're trying to do, but it is another option.